# Getting a error in Spring Configuration XML file:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn Spring MVC and trying some sample applications. I am getting an error Line 14 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 61; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. I am getting stuck in the middle because of this error. Please help me to fix the error.

My Spring Configuration XML file:

```xml
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

        xsi:schemalocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">  

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties">  
        </context:property-placeholder>  
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.hibernate">  
        </context:component-scan>  

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager">  
        </tx:annotation-driven>  

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"                        id="jspViewResolver">  
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">           </property>  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>  
       </bean>  

       <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">  
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>  
      <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>  
      <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>  
      <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>  
      </bean>  

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory">  
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
      <property name="annotatedClasses">  
      <list>  
      <value>com.spring.hibernate.model.Employee</value>  
      </list>  
     </property>  
    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
    <props>  
     <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>  
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
     <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}  </prop>      
        </props>  
      </property>  
     </bean>  


 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" id="hibernateTransactionManager">  
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>  
  </bean>  
  </beans>
```

This is the line, I am getting the error exactly from the configuration file:http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"

My Console:

```
Mar 19, 2014 12:09:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Riya/software_downloads/eclipse/jre/bin/server;C:/Riya/software_downloads/eclipse/jre/bin;C:/Riya/software_downloads/eclipse/jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;;C:\Riya\software_downloads\eclipse;;.
Mar 19, 2014 12:09:26 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringHibernateApp' did not find a matching property.
Mar 19, 2014 12:09:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
Mar 19, 2014 12:09:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 19, 2014 12:09:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 442 ms
Mar 19, 2014 12:09:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 19, 2014 12:09:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Mar 19, 2014 12:09:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'sdnext'
Mar 19, 2014 12:09:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 14 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 61; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 61; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 29 more

Mar 19, 2014 12:09:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /SpringHibernateApp threw load() exception
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 61; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Mar 19, 2014 12:09:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
Mar 19, 2014 12:09:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 19, 2014 12:09:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1904 ms
```

Comment: It doesn't look like an error in your application context, but in the `sdnext-servlet.xml` file, on line 14.  unless you named your application context xml "sdnext-servlet.xml".

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer so that I can understand your point correctly.

Answer (score 4):

XML is case-sensitive - you need `xsi:schemaLocation` (capital L), not `xsi:schemalocation` (small l).

The error is because you haven't provided an `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute, so the schema validator doesn't know where to find the schema declarations for the elements you're using in the XML file.

Comment: Yes.you are right. The error got fixed, now it moved further and showing a different error. I will fix that. Thanks for pinpointing it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.hibernate" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        id="jspViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
        </property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
        id="sessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.spring.hibernate.model.Employee</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}  </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        id="hibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: The error got fixed by changing schemalocation as schemaLocation with capital L in location and you too gave proper sdnext-servlet.xml with this change.Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Riya, no problem, yrw :)

Answer (score 0):

try to copy-paste this into your xml, there is a problem

```
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
```

Comment: Its not making any difference. Seems both are same.

Comment: I was getting the same exception with your xml, but when I replaced http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans from my working xml the error disappeared

Comment: may be you have changed the schemalocation into schemaLocation in your xml and it worked i guess. Bcoz after doing this change it got fixed for me.